# How to update Mongo DB by parsing a list of object

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using c#
one of the mongo db document is in such structure

```
Class QuestionData{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<NotesQuestion> Question { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to do a updating. I write the update as following:

```
var update = Update.Set("Question", data.Question);
```

The 'data' is a type of QuestionData.
But now it says "invalid argument" of data.Question.
If I change it to

```
  var update = Update.Set("Question", data.Question.ToJson());
```

It has no problem. But I don't want to save it as json string.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Mongo saves everything in JSON...?

Comment: It saves the Question as Array if I don't convert it into json.

Comment: @StevenZack What do you want MongoDB to store a `List<NotesQuestion>` as if not an array of objects? What does the `NotesQuestion` class look like? Is it serializable?

Answer (score 0):

With my own model classes,

```
internal class QuestionData
{
  [BsonId] public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("type")] public string Type { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("qnotes")] public QuestionNote[] QuestionNotes { get; set; }
}

[BsonNoId] internal class QuestionNote
{
  [BsonElement("q")] public string Question { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("n")] public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

you can overwrite the whole bson array like:

```
// get client, database, collection ...
var col = Database.GetCollection<QuestionData>("questions");
// QuestionNote[] toModifyWith = ... 
var udb = Builders<QuestionData>.Update;
var fdb = Builders<QuestionData>.Filter;
var ur = await col.UpdateManyAsync(fdb.Empty, udb.Set(x => x.QuestionNotes, toModifyWith ));
```